# Compile Error: Argument Not Optional on Find in a Word document using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have Excel_Doc_A and Word_Doc_A.

Excel_Doc_A will use VBA to:
-refer to Word_Doc_A,
-find certain text values (in this example, "**TITLE**"),
-insert a hyperlink into that text field,
-change the text to what is indicated in Excel_Doc_A,
-save the Word_Doc_A as a new file Word_Doc_B, that has all the text replaced and hyperlinks included.

I get

> Compile Error: Argument Not Optional on Find

on the line

```
Set myFind = myRange.Find
```

```vb
Public Sub testing_1()

Dim documentApplication As Word.Application
Dim documentDocument As Word.Document

Set narApplication = CreateObject("word.application")
Set narDocument = narApplication.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/document_template.docx")

Dim TITLE As String
Dim myRange As range
Dim myFind As Find
Dim filePath As String

TITLE = range("B1")

'For each value, find it's value in the blankdocument
Set myRange = narDocument.Content
Set myFind = myRange.Find
With myFind
    .Text = "__TITLE__"
    searchResult = .Execute
    .Replacement.Text = TITLE
End With

narDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=myRange, Address:="http://www.google.com", TextToDisplay:="__TITLE__ " 
    
filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/document_test.docx"
narDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=filePath

'Cleanup
narDocument.Quit False
Set narApplication = Nothing
Set narDocument = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim myFind As Find` don't think that's a valid data type? Edit: unless you wrote a class?

Comment: Also, you execute the Find before you set the replacement text, needs to be executed after.

Answer (score 2):

`Dim myRange As Range` is implicitly `As Excel.Range`. You get a compile error because `Set myFind = myRange.Find` is referencing the *Excel* [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) method. You need members from the *Word* object model.

Early-binding:

```
Dim myRange As Word.Range
Dim myFind As Word.Find
```

Late-binding:

```
Dim myRange As Object
Dim myFind As Object
```

---

It would be best to be consistent.

Early-binding:

```
Dim documentApplication As Word.Application
Dim documentDocument As Word.Document
Set narApplication = New Word.Application
```

Late-binding:

```
Dim documentApplication As Object
Dim documentDocument As Object
Set narApplication = CreateObject("word.application")
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes total sense. Newb question, what do you mean by early binding and late binding?